# Any ideas why my FileUpload is showing no file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, telerik, radgrid

I have a simple FileUpload box that is alble to accept files and save them to a location on a server on one web page, but the page I'm working on now has a form view inside of a radPageView, inside of a RadMultiPageView. When I attempt to see if there is a file in the FileUpload control, I am met with null values every time, eventhough I'm loading in a file. Here are some snippets of my code, trimmed down a little. Part of the problem is that in all of the tutorials I've found online, users are entering some of this information in the vb for the button click event, where I'm entering it in the `xyz Handles .Updating` section.

The prolem I run into is that when I get to the `FileUpload1.HasFile` it shows that there is no file, even if I have uploaded one. In fact, it shows Null, as if I haven't properly connected to the FileUpload control. I messed around with different ways to connect to the FileUpload control, but none of them really worked.

```
    <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="multiPage"
        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid">
        <telerik:RadPageView ID="pvMemoDoc" runat="server">
            <asp:FormView ID="fvMemoDoc" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" DataSourceID="dsMemos"
                DataKeyNames="coreDocID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <table class="tblNoSpace">
                        [...Other Code...]
                        <%--Begin file upload section--%>
                        <tr>

                            <td class="fieldLabel">File to upload:<br />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="600" ToolTip="Browse for file"   />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblFU1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Visible="false"
                                    Text="(only select new file if you wish to replace existing file)"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateMemo" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update Memo"
                                    CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="MemoInformation"
                                    ToolTip="Save updates" />&nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
        </telerik:RadPageView>

        [...Other Code...]

    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

VB Code:

```
Private Sub DsMemo_Updating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs) Handles dsMemos.Updating
    Dim FileUpload1 As FileUpload = CType(fvMemoDoc.FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)
    'Dim FileUpload1 As FileUpload = CType(fvMemoDoc.Controls(0).Controls(0).FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)
    'Dim FileUpload1 As FileUpload = CType(fvMemoDoc.Controls(0).FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)
    'Dim FileUpload1 As FileUpload = TryCast(updateButton.Parent.Parent.FindControl("FileUpload1"), FileUpload)

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        [...Other Code Here..]
        [...Never gets past FileUpload1.HasFile...]
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you use UpdatePanel or Ajax? How do you trigger DsMemo_Updating method?

Comment: When I click the update button, the rest of the data in the form is data bound to an sql data source. It has the update command set to reach out and use a stored procedure on the sql server. I wanted to pull the file upload information into VB so that I could trigger different events depending on whether or not the person had uploaded a file.

Comment: It appears that the `telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl` is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears after some tinkering that there was an issue with modify versus read/write permissions.
The way that control was working is that it would store a temporary file and then delete it off of the server, so that is why no file was showing.

Giving the web app modify access to the folder where the temporary files are stored solved my issue.